# Powershell register scheduled task that respects daylight savings time

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I use PowerShell scheduled tasks via the `Register-ScheduledTask` and `New-ScheduledTaskTrigger` cmdlets to create reminders for myself throughout the day.
When Daylight Savings Time hit, all those reminders became an hour off.

What can I do to avoid this? It would probably require the task triggers to be in local time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scheduled task trigger must be modified to be in local time.

1. Create your trigger as normal

   ```
   $trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 10:15am
   ```
2. Then edit the trigger's StartBoundary property:

   ```
   $trigger.StartBoundary = [DateTime]::Parse($trigger.StartBoundary).ToLocalTime().ToString("s")
   ```

Explanation: When you create the trigger with `New-ScheduledTaskTrigger,` the time you specify is converted to UTC time and saved as a string in the trigger's `StartBoundary` property. On my machine, 10:15am produces a $`trigger.StartBoundary` of "`2017-12-19T15:15:00Z"`, where the "Z" indicates UTC time. To specify a local time, we need to convert this date back into local time and remove the "Z"; we want `"2017-12-19T10:15:00"`. The snippet above parses the date string, converts it to local time, and formats it in the correct format.

If you need to do this a lot you may find this function helpful:

```
function Fix-Trigger {
    param( [parameter(ValueFromPipeline)] [CimInstance] $trigger )
    $newTrigger = $trigger.Clone()
    $newTrigger.StartBoundary = [DateTime]::Parse(
        $trigger.StartBoundary).ToLocalTime().ToString("s")
    $newTrigger
}

# Example usage:
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 10:15am | Fix-Trigger
```

This is all from [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e1dad780-6a99-44f2-9688-041e7026854b/quotsynchronize-across-time-zonesquot-scheduled-task-option-and-newscheduledtasktrigger?forum=winserverpowershell&prof=required).